# Import text documents to graph database through RDF triples

Tags: python, rdf, stanford-nlp, graphdb

I have a list of documents (summary text and full document link). I am using [`OpenIE`](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html) on the summary text to get RDF triples.

How can I import the RDF triples and associated full document links in [`GraphDB`](https://www.ontotext.com/products/graphdb/) for querying using SparkQL?

Comment: just read the GraphDB docs how to load RDF data, or what did not work?

Comment: I don't have data in `RDF` format, I used OpenIE to generate (subject, relation, object). How can I convert these to RDF format to import into GrapDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OpenIE seems to "produce relation triples in a tab separated format", you could save it as a [TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) file, which can be imported into GraphDB: ["Import tabular data with OntoRefine"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kztm6.png)

After importing the file, you can click on "RDF Mapping" in the top right corner.

GraphDB [offers](https://www.ontotext.com/knowledgehub/fundamentals/ontorefine-2/) a video tutorial showing how to use SPARQL for that:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpWM1WBq2gk